# How to detect the mouse cursor size across all platforms in C++?

Tags: c++, mouse

Is there a way to detect the mouse cursor size in C++ across all platforms? I know there is a way to do it with WINAPI, just how do you do it without using WINAPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to detect the mouse cursor size in C++ across all platforms?

No. C++ doesn't have any concept of a cursor (this is a function of the OS). However, there are libraries that allow you to interact with the OS in a cross platform way. These libraries still use platform specific APIs under the hood, but they provide a convenient abstraction for you.

Depending on your other requirements, [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) might be helpful. After a quick skim of the [QCursor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcursor.html) class, it looks like you can't get the size of the cursor, but you can set it (they recommend setting it to 32x32 because it's supported on all platforms).